# Passing Encrypted ID from jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In MVC,
I have used jquery templates. It is returning ID and I have setup one link in which that ID is passing. But I want to encrypt that ID using server side function.

```
{#template PAYMENTLINK}
                    <li class="scale-list-1">
                        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="PaymentUrl({$T.PackageId});">Pay</a>
                    </li>
                {#/template PAYMENTLINK}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt and decrypt methods that we use in our solution. All that you need to is id.ToString(), cause method gets the string as input

```
        public string Decrypt(string inputValue)
        {
            byte[] inputEquivalent = Convert.FromBase64String(inputValue.Replace(" ", "+"));

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (
                    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.CryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(inputEquivalent, 0, inputEquivalent.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    cryptoStream.Close();
                    return new UTF8Encoding().GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the encrypted text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="inputValue">The input value.</param>
        /// <returns>Encrypted string</returns>
        public string Encrypt(string inputValue)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (
                    var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.CryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] toEncrypt = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(inputValue);
                    cryptoStream.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    byte[] ret = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    cryptoStream.Close();
                    memoryStream.Close();

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(ret);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes above methods I already have.. I want to pass javascript value through this methods in my code above.